# textbox message based on drop down list selected value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, cascadingdropdown

my dropdownlist have value where user choose A1, textbox will show +1, choose A2, message show +2, if B1, message show -1, and B2 message show -2. i choose A1, +1 comes out and A2, +2 appear. however, when i choose B1, +1 appear and B2, +2. why does As answer only appear not Bs ? need help.

my aspx.cs

```
protected void ddlJM1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int IntentID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlJM1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    FillYes(IntentID);

    if (ddlJM1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        ddlJM2.Enabled = true;
        ddlJM3.Enabled = false;
        ddlJM2.SelectedIndex = 0;
        lblMsgJM.Text = "";
    }

    if (ddlJM1.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        ddlJM2.Enabled = true;
        ddlJM2.SelectedIndex = 0;

        ddlJM3.Enabled = false;
        lblMsgJM.Text = "";
    }

}

protected void ddlJM2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int YesID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlJM2.SelectedValue.ToString());
    FillJob(YesID);

    if (ddlJM2.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        ddlJM3.Enabled = true;
        lblMsgJM.Text = "";
    }

    if (ddlJM2.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        ddlJM3.Enabled = false;

    }

    if (ddlJM2.SelectedIndex == 3)
    {
        ddlJM3.Enabled = true;
        lblMsgJM.Text = "";
    }

    if (ddlJM2.SelectedIndex == 4)
    {
        ddlJM3.Enabled = false;
        lblMsgJM.Text = "Please consult / review with ODD focal person";
    }

}


 protected void ddlJM3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlJM3.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        lblMsgJM.Text = "+1";
    }
    if (ddlJM3.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        lblMsgJM.Text = "+2";
    }

     if (ddlJM3.SelectedIndex == 3)
    {
        lblMsgJM.Text = "-1";
    }
    if (ddlJM3.SelectedIndex == 4)
    {
        lblMsgJM.Text = "-2";
    }
}

 private void FillJob(int YesID) //for ddlJM3
    {
        string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT AlphabetID, Alphabet FROM TableJob WHERE YesID =@YesID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YesID", YesID);
        DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        con.Open();
        dAdapter.Fill(objDs);
        con.Close();

        if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlJM3.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
            ddlJM3.DataTextField = "Alpahabet";
            ddlJM3.DataValueField = "AlphabetID";
            ddlJM3.DataBind();
            ddlJM3.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");

        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please compare selected value like this

```
protected void ddlJM3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlJM3.SelectedItem.Text.ToLower() == "a1")
    {
        lblMsgJM.Text = "+1";
    }
    if (ddlJM3.SelectedItem.Text.ToLower() == "a2")
    {
        lblMsgJM.Text = "+2";
    }

    if (ddlJM3.SelectedItem.Text.ToLower() == "b1")
    {
        lblMsgJM.Text = "-1";
    }
    if (ddlJM3.SelectedItem.Text.ToLower() == "b2")
    {
        lblMsgJM.Text = "-2";
    }
}
```

Comment: but i'm using ID since my dropdownlist are cascading ddl, so ==1 represent A1, ==2 is A2 and so on, i used your way but still it wont work

Comment: Can you check and tell me what selected value every time comes?

Comment: i put ID 1 for A1, 2 for A2, 3 for B1, 4 for B2, but value come out, +1 when i select A1, +2 for A2, but +1 when i choose B1 and +2 when i choose B2.  the answer for B's doesnt come out

Comment: if you use index then might be set all of -1 because it's start to 0. I think it's working           
                                                                                                                                   if (ddlJM3.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        lblMsgJM.Text = "+1";
    }
    if (ddlJM3.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        lblMsgJM.Text = "+2";
    }

     if (ddlJM3.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        lblMsgJM.Text = "-1";
    }
    if (ddlJM3.SelectedIndex == 3)
    {
        lblMsgJM.Text = "-2";
    }

Comment: please get new solution